# For $n$ urns we put $n+5$ balls in them. What's the probability for no urn being empty if the balls are all the same & if the balls are all distinct?

Tags: probability

I don't get why there should be a different result depending if the balls are all of the same color or if all balls have a different color.

What is meant by "For $n$ urns we put $n+5$ balls in them" is that we got $8$ balls for $3$ urns e.g.

Comment: In reality the balls are all physically distinct even if they are the same colour, and that is the way to go if you want to try this experiment.  But in some people's minds there is an equally probable distribution which ignores such distinctions

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [our policy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question&ved=2ahUKEwjTzKSytMTpAhXGb30KHThEDxwQFjABegQIDhAF&usg=AOvVaw3O5bRgjEVERMyuyayWLY4c), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Is your question what is in the title?  Or is your question what is in your body?  In response to the body... who says that there should be a different result depending on if the balls are the same color or different?  Under the most common interpretations of the problem in the title they won't be different.

Comment: As for what it means to put $n+5$ balls into $n$ urns randomly... the most common interpretation is that we take each ball in sequence and uniformly and independently decide which urn to place it in... making the $n^{(n+5)}$ different sequences of such choices equally likely, those different sequences of choices directly corresponding to the different outcomes of distinct balls in the urns (*with indistinct balls, you will have multiple of these sequences corresponding to the same outcome, but this is irrelevant.  Rather than looking at the outcome, we look at the sequence leading to it*)

Comment: As for an approach... inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

For your case of $8$ balls in $3$ urns then

- unconstrained there are $3^8=6561$ possibilities, and these can reasonably be seen as equally probable
- but $3$ of the $6561$ have all the balls in one urn and $762$ have all the balls in exactly two urns,
- leaving $5796$ possible patterns with no urn empty  and a probability of $\frac{5796}{6561} \approx 0.8834$

In reality the balls are all physically distinct even if they are the same colour, and that is the way to go if you want to try this experiment. But in some people's minds there is a distribution which ignores such distinctions

Their calculation would be that if there are $8$ indistinguishable balls than $3$ distinguishable urns, then a stars and bars calculation would suggest ${10 \choose 2}=45$ possible patterns of which $3$ having all the balls in one urn and $21$ having all the balls in exactly two urns, leaving $21$ possible patterns with no urn empty and suggesting a probability of $\frac{21}{45} \approx 0.4667$

But I would argue that in the second case the patterns considered are not equally probable; in a reasonable interpretation, putting all eight balls in the first urn has a probability of $\frac{1}{6561}$ not $\frac{1}{45}$, no matter what colour the balls are.  Allowing for this will lead back to the first result

Comment: Could you do this on a general example for n urns?

Comment: Yes I could, but I suspect it would be pedagogically better if you tried

Comment: I know from where you got 3^8 because for each ball there are three possibilities where it can land (those three urns)

But I don't get from where you 762 got from

Comment: In quantum reality there do exist absolutely indistinguishable objects (fermions and bosons), which therefore do not obey the classical (Boltzmann) statistics. :)

Comment: @Student If there is one urn then there is $1^8$ way of filling it with $8$ balls.  If there are $2$ urns then there are $2^8 - {2 \choose 1}1=254$ ways of filling the two urns, none empty, with $8$ balls.  If there are $3$ urns then there are $3^8 - {3 \choose 2}254 - {3 \choose 1}=5796$ ways of filling the three urns, none empty, with $8$ balls.  Meanwhile ${3 \choose 2}254 = 756$ and $ {3 \choose 1}1 = 3$

Comment: @user - if the balls are macroscopic, it is quite difficult to add up the spinstates to see whether they are fermions following Fermi–Dirac statistics or bosons following Bose–Einstein statistics.  So I will stick with standard statistics